# Unable to boot from USB on Sony Vaio

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot

This is the first time I encounter this issue. I can't boot from USB drive on a Sony Vaio PCG-21313M. I set the external device as first choice and enabled it. Also I tested the usb (Windows 7) on other laptops and it boots fine. The computer doesn't boot properly not even in safe mode.

Comment: external device thumb drive or cd/dvd drive? If external cd/dvd, does bios see the drive on boot? Does it use 2 usb ports to power up or one? netbook plugged in or on battery?

Comment: Try pressing F12 during boot, to bring it up in the network BIOS.

Comment: I don't have an external cd rom. It is a mini laptop, so it should boot from usb... netbook plugged in.

Comment: Press the `F2/F12` whatever key which belongs to enter in the Bios setup and then change the boot sequence, also change it when you have plugged in the bootable USB drive, it will show up there by its name whatever you have chooses for it and put it on the top. As my personal experience with my laptop there are two options for the bootable USB drive. **1:** USB Drive **2:** USB key. 1st one boot form the external HDD and 2nd boot form the bootable USB drive.

Comment: @avirk From the question you can see that I've already done that.

Comment: Yes it seems but I have mentioned two reasons for that too.  Can you please upload a screenshot of Bios settings with plugged USB? It will very helpful to understand the booting priority for us. You can upload it on www.imgur.com and then post that link through editing your question because you can't upload the pics due to your reputation.

Comment: you can try pressing F11 during boot process to go directly to USB boot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have experiences similar issue, then I found Boot mode setting in BIOS. It was set on `UEFI` and I changed it to `Legacy` and it works!
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Funnily enough this worked for my Vaio. In the past I've not been able to use Legacy install modes on my computers, always had to use UEFI, so hadn't considered changing this option until your answer. +1 for you :) 

(Maybe difference between custom made PC's and 'off-the-shelf' PC's?)

Answer (score 3):

If your drive is bootable then follow this step.

1. Go to bios by pressing "F2" on power on, to enter bios.
2. On boot priority section enable "external boot".
3. Set "external" as first priority and "internal hdd" as last. by pressing "F5/F6"

I am sure it will work, Make sure "internal hdd" is at last priority, because if it is not sometime it did not boot from "eternal" although it is set as first priority. unknown result.

If it did not work possibly you may problem with your external drive or data(boot-sector).

Answer (score 1):

I tried using an ubuntu usb with no success. Then I tried using nolapic feature of ubuntu and it finally booted as a virtual machine, without installing. It let me backup my hdd. Hope this solution might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the BIOS and change your boot location (Removable Disk) and Disable your Hard Drive. When finish your Windows 7 installation, return to the BIOS and Enable your Hard drive.